# Wrong type of input

Tags: c++

I have the code below, so basically my problem is: when someone input a character like 'a', it will pop a message that requires a re-input

I tried using the ASCII:
`if (a >= 97 && a <= 122)` but it still didn't work

```
double a;
cin >> a;
if (a >= 'a' && a <= 'z')
    {
        cout << "Wrong input, please re-input a:  " << endl;
        cin >> a;
    }
cout << a;
```

I expect it to pop the message to re-input but the actual output is always `0` no matter what character I input

Comment: Did you mean to use `char a;` instead of `double a;`?

Comment: You are trying to get the user to input a `double` and you declare a double variable. But then you write code as if the double variable has suddently because a `char` variable just because the user typed a character. I'm sorry but C++ doesn't work like that. `a` is a double variable and `a >= 'a'` does not make any sense no matter what the user types in.

Answer (score 1):

The state of a stream can be checked by using it directly in a condition. If all is okay it "returns" true, otherwise "false". So you can do e.g.

```
if (!(cin >> a))
{
    // Invalid input, or other error
}
```

On invalid input you need to [clear](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear) the state.

Note that if the input is invalid then the input will not be read, and the next time you attempt to read you will read the exact same input that failed the first time. One way to solve it is to [ignore](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) the rest of the line. Another is to [read a whole line into a string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) that you then put into an [input string stream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) for the parsing of the input.